# Update activerecord relation given a hash of multiple entries

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm quite new to Rails, so be gentle :)

I have the following models set-up:

```
class User
   has_many :it_certificates, :class_name => 'UserCertificate'

class UserCertificate
   belongs_to :skill
```

Given the following input (in JSON)

```
{
   "certificates":[
      { // update
         "id":1,
         "name":"Agile Web Dev 2",
         "entity":"Agile Masters!",
         "non_it":false,
         "date_items":{
            "month":10,
            "year":2012
         },
         "skill": {
            "id":57
         }
      },
      { // create
         "name":"Agile Web Dev 1",
         "entity":"Agile Masters!",
         "non_it":false,
         "date_items":{
            "month":10,
            "year":2011
         },
         "skill": {
            "id":58
         }
      }     
   ]
}
```

How's the easiest way to update the information for the relation it_certificates?

I've been looking to update_all but it doesn't match my needs (it only updates given fields with the same value).

So I've been struggling around with the approach of iterating over each of these records and then update them one-by-one. 
I mean struggling because it looks to me there are lots of things I have to care of when the idea of Rails is the opposite.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So, here's my solution for now:

```
  def self.update_from_hash(data, user_id)
    self.transaction do
      data.each do |certificate|
        if certificate[:id] == nil
          # create
          if !self.create(
             :name => certificate[:name],
             :entity => certificate[:entity],
             :user_id => user_id,
             :non_it => certificate[:non_it],
             :skill_id => certificate[:skill][:id],
             :date => self.build_date_from_items(certificate[:date_items][:month], certificate[:date_items][:year])
          )
            raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
          end
        else
          # update
          if !self.update(certificate[:id], {
              :name => certificate[:name],
              :entity => certificate[:entity],
              :non_it => certificate[:non_it],
              :skill_id => certificate[:skill][:id],
              :date => self.build_date_from_items(certificate[:date_items][:month], certificate[:date_items][:year])
          })
            raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
          end
        end
      end
    end
    return true
  end
```

It works, but I'm still expecting a more elegant solution :)